# explicacion de codigo con firebase:_realtime

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Estoy iniciando en firebase y quisiera que alguien me pudiera ayudar explicándome mas a fondo el siguiente codigo mis duas estan en principalmente:

`Map<dynamic,dynamic>`

`firebaseVar.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot)`

```
var firebaseVar = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Principal');
    firebaseVar.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
      Map<dynamic,dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
      values.forEach((key,values){
        if(key=="title"){
          print(values);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que hace el método `once` es que solo escucha una vez los resultados, no está en constante escucha.

Puedes encontrar más info aquí: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#once

Ahora, una vez que tienes los resultados de `Firebase`, lo que obtienes es un `DataSnapshot` , son los datos del documento y para poder acceder a ellos necesitas usar el getter value.

```
 Map<dynamic,dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
```

El value lo que te trae es un Map con llave y valor (key/value).

Al usar esto

```
 values.forEach((key,values){
    if(key=="title"){
      print(values);
    }
  });
```

Estas recorriendo todas las llaves que tienes en ese `Map` y verificar si una de las llaves se llama `title`, si es así , estás imprimiendo el valor que trae esa llave.

Ejemplo, supongamos que el mapa de datos es así :

```
{"id" : 12345, 
 "name" : "User",
 "title" : "Title for User"
 }
```

Con el código que usas, te va a imprimir "Title for User", que es el valor que tiene el `key` title.

Si quieres acceder a un valor específico , solo hazlo así:

```
  Map<dynamic,dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
  final id = values["id"];
  final name = values["name"];
  final title = values["title"];
```